# How to "best" exit multiple trades?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, risk-management

Let say I have N opened trades (N = s + b) that are partialy hedged, and paritaly not. In general s != b. Some of them are market sell orders (s), and the rest of them are market buy orders (b). They were all opened some time ago and currently they experience stochastic value change according to price dynamics.

I would like to close them one by one using... some optimal strategy. Can this problem be formulated in means of inventory holding risk, profit maximization or any other useful metric?

My first thought was to exit largest winner when cumulative profit is positive, and exit least looser when cumulative profit is negative - but is this realy useful??? (now i think it's not)

Please give me some advice. **Can this be done optimally?**

Comment: I think that must depend on more assumptions on the future you're making and less on the past. Imagine you were handed this portfolio, what would you do? Probably you would keep those positions with a positive expectation and reduce those with a negative expectation .

Comment: You are right Bob.  I'm looking for some quantitative online solution with established theoretical framework. I have profit maximization entry strategy, but it acumulates inventory, and this induce risk. I want to limit this risk by optimal exit strategy.

Comment: I like this question. I had a similar question about how to unwind a portfolio optimising for execution costs and market risk (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59869/unwinding-a-portfolio), but in that model I was assuming no future knowledge, would be interesting to consider the case when you do.

Comment: I think this question is a but underspecified. Why isn't: execute N market orders to flatten your positions a valid answer? In what way does that strategy not give the desired result?